# If $A$ is a non-empty set, and $G,H$ are equivalence relations in $A$. How to prove that $(A/H)/(G/H) \approx A/G$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need show that exist a biyective function $f:(A/H)/(G/H) \rightarrow A/G$.

Let $A/H=\{H_x : x\in A\}$, $G/H=\{(H_x,H_y) : (x,y)\in G\}$, then:

$(A/H)/(G/H)=\{ (G/H)_{Hx} : H_x\in (A/H)  \}$

I've thought of the following function such that $ (G_x) = f ((G / H)_{ Hx}) $, but I do not know how to show that $ f $ is a function, much less that $ f $ is a bijective function.

I'm doing the function well?, is there a simpler function? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I haven't seen these notations before. I assume $H_x$ means the equivalence class of $x$ for the equivalence relation $H$, right?

Comment: @user49640 Yes.

Comment: With the definition you've given of $G/H$, it seems $G/H$ might not be an equivalence relation on $A/H$. Is that a problem?

Comment: @user49640 By a theorem i know that $G/H$ is a equivalence relation in $A/G$. The problem is show that exist a biyective function between $(A/H)/(G/H)$ and $A/G.$

Comment: If the classes of $H$ are $\{a\}, \{b,b'\},\{c\}$ and the classes of $G$ are $\{a,b\}, \{b',c\}$, then $(H_a,H_b) \in G/H$ and $(H_b,H_c) = (H_{b'},H_c) \in G/H$, but $(H_a,H_c) \not\in G/H$.

Comment: This looks like some [isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem), in the form given for groups.